# Regular expression to cover time duration

Tags: regex, range

I want to write a regex to cover time duration 020000AM to 030200 AM. [02:00:00 - 03:02:00]
I've done the below one, but it seems it is wrong.

```
[02<4#>|030[0|1|2]]<2#>
```

Can anyone help me on this....

Comment: Regex really isn't built for complex ranges like this, but I can try to whip something up. To help test, you may want to update your question with example matches and example failures.

Comment: You can craft a regex for this requirement, but its not the right tool for the job, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expanded expression:

```
02[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]|03(?:0[01][0-5][0-9]|0200)
```

Here is the expanded expression split up so you can read it "easier":

```
 02
 [0-5][0-9]
 [0-5][0-9]
|
 03
 (?:
   0[01]
   [0-5][0-9]
  |
   02
   00
 )
```

Here is an "optimized" expression (you can see it's a lot more difficult to read and a lot more difficult to change the range):

```
0(?:2[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]|30(?:[01][0-5][0-9]|200))
```